# JavaScript converting the string "constructor" to [Function: Object]

Tags: javascript, parsing, types

I'm building a parser for a simple interpreter in JavaScript. I have a preprocessor method that removes specific tokens from an input list of tokens produced by the tokenizer:

```
const tokenizer = new Tokenizer();
let program = [];
let symbols = {};

tokenizer.init(mainFile, null);
let tokens = tokenizer.exec(mainFile);

for (let i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    const lookahead = [
        tokens[i+1],
        tokens[i+2]
    ];
    if (tokens[i].type == 'PRE_DEFINE') {
        if (lookahead[0].type == 'IDENTIFIER') {
            symbols[tokens[i+1].value] = String(lookahead[1].value);
            i+=3;
        } else {
            throw new PreprocessorError(`Unexpected token "${lookahead[0].value}"`);
        }            
    }

    if (tokens[i].type == 'IDENTIFIER' && String(tokens[i].value) in symbols) {
        program.push(symbols[tokens[i].value]);
    } else {
        program.push(tokens[i].value);
    }
}
return program;
```

Each token is an object like this, with both type and value being strings:

```
// Affected constructor identifier token
{
    type: 'IDENTIFIER',
    value: 'constructor'
},
// Number token
{
    type: 'NUMBERLITERAL',
    value: '10'
}
```

Somewhere in this function, when `tokens[i].value == 'constructor'`, said value is being converted to the actual JS keyword constructor (I would assume) and is showing up in debug as [Function: Object]. The word 'constructor' appearing in a token has caused no issues elsewhere in the code where it's handled and appears normal when `console.log`'d directly before this loop, so I'm quite confused. Could someone point me in the direction of an explanation here?

I have added several calls to String() to attempt to force `'constructor'` to remain a string, but nothing seems to work.

I would assume that I've missed something in my code, but is it possible this is a JS issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `symbols` is a plain object, so it has a [`constructor` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) which exists on the prototype. Reading that property returns a constructor, which is a function:

```js
console.log("constructor" in {});
console.log(typeof ({})["constructor"]);
```

For a lookup, an object which does not have a prototype can be used. These are created with `Object.create(null)`:

```js
let program = [];
let symbols = Object.create(null);

let tokens = [
  {
      type: 'IDENTIFIER',
      value: 'constructor'
  },
  {
      type: 'NUMBERLITERAL',
      value: '10'
  }
]

for (let i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    const lookahead = [
        tokens[i+1],
        tokens[i+2]
    ];
    if (tokens[i].type == 'PRE_DEFINE') {
        if (lookahead[0].type == 'IDENTIFIER') {
            symbols[tokens[i+1].value] = String(lookahead[1].value);
            i+=3;
        } else {
            throw new PreprocessorError(`Unexpected token "${lookahead[0].value}"`);
        }            
    }
    
    if (tokens[i].type == 'IDENTIFIER' && tokens[i].value in symbols) {
        program.push(symbols[tokens[i].value]);
    } else {
        program.push(tokens[i].value);
    }
}
console.log(program);
```

It might be worth considering using [a Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot. As a sidenote, `"constructor" in (new Map())` returns true, so I think Object.create(null) is the way to go here.

Comment: @WillHopkins you're supposed to use `Map#has()` to check for existence of a key, `Map#get()` to retrieve the value and `Map#set()` to set it. `in` has no place when you operate with maps.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. That'll definitely come in handy in the future, though I ended up using an object with a null prototype and that worked for me in this scenario.